# Apex Repeat isnot showing any values

Tags: visualforce

vf page:

```
   <table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%"> 
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D3D3D3">Partner Name</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;background-color: #8D8E92">Hybrid Cloud-Cloud Management and Automation</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;background-color: #8D8E92">Hybrid Cloud-Data Center Vitualization</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;background-color: #8D8E92">Hybrid Cloud,Multi Cloud-VMware Cloud on AWS</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;background-color: #8D8E92">Modernize Apps</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;background-color: #8D8E92">Network Virtualization</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;background-color: #8D8E92">Empower Digital Workspace</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>   
    <apex:repeat value="{!mscAdminList}" var="a">         
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:center;background-color:#D3D3D3;">"{!a.IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c}"</th>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:center; background-color:#32CD32">"{!a.IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c}"</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:center; background-color:#32CD32">"{!a.IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c}"</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:center;background-color:#A9A9A9">"{!a.IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c}"</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:center;background-color:#A9A9A9">"{!a.IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c}"</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:center; background-color:#32CD32">"{!a.IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c}"</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:center; background-color:#32CD32">"{!a.IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c}"</td>
        </apex:repeat>

    </tr>
    </table>
```

Controller:

```
public class PartnerRedinessController {
      public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
      public List<IT_Priority_MSC_Admin__c> mscAdminList{get;set;}
      public PartnerRedinessController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
     {
        //currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
       // Account ac=[select id,Geo__c,country_type__c from account where 
    Id=:currentRecordId];
        List<IT_Priority_MSC_Admin__c> mscAdminList=[select 
    id,Country_Status__c,IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c,Geo__c from 
     IT_Priority_MSC_Admin__c];
        system.debug('mscAdminList@@@@'+mscAdminList);

 }
 }
```

values coming properly in "mscAdminList"(controller) side but itsnit showing any value in vf page

Comment: can you put the table in a section or page block and put render tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
List<IT_Priority_MSC_Admin__c> mscAdminList=[select 
id,Country_Status__c,IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c,Geo__c from 
 IT_Priority_MSC_Admin__c];
```

to

```
mscAdminList=[select 
    id,Country_Status__c,IT_Priority_MSC_Tier__c,Geo__c from 
     IT_Priority_MSC_Admin__c];
```

in your constructor and your problem would get resolve.

Comment: both are same only knw what was the issue

Comment: @SFDCFAN - you were redeclaring mscAdminList within the Constructor but the page references the congtroller's instance variable mscAdminList - two different memory locations